# Meteor -- How to connect to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to meteor platform.
I have created a meteor project.
Need help to change db. I have created a mongodb in https://mongolab.com/. It provided connection string and I am able to successfully connect to that DB from terminal(Ubuntu).
I want to connect to mongodb hosted in https://mongolab.com/. How can I update connection string in meteor project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Export the `MONGO_URL` environment variable with the MongoLab connection string like this `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/your_db`

Then, run `meteor` as usual.